# WSO2 admin service APIKeyMgtSubscriberService function getApplicationAccessToken returns revoked key

Tags: wso2

I am using WSO2 admin SOAP service `APIKeyMgtSubscriberService`, trying to invoke `getApplicationAccessToken` function.

If I make first call to this function, right after application creation in the web interface, it will return correct access_key.

But if I calls `renewAccessToken` function or make ReGenerate in the web - next call to `getApplicationAccessToken` will return previous revoked token instead of new one.

How to get currently active token from my java application?